# Adding objects as properties of a master object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have a master object, for example:

MasterObj = {
property1: ...
method1: ...
}

and multiple other objects:

obj1 = {
properties and methods...
},

obj2 = {
properties and methods...
}

I need to make each object as a property of the master object, like:

MasterObj.obj1 = obj1;
MasterObj.obj2 = obj2;

So that I can use the properties and methods of each little object in this way:

MasterObject.obj1.methodOfObj1(), etc...

and the original properties and methods of the MasterObject.

Is there any efficient way to add each object to the master, without having to do it for each object individually?

Thanks!

Comment: Make a single property with an array of objects. Then you can add them in a loop.

Comment: `MasterObj.objects = [obj1, obj2, ...]`

Comment: Could you please send me an example? This way I have a property (objects) that will hold an array of objects, but I want to access a property or method of obj1 as MasterObj.obj1.propertyOrmethod.

Comment: `MasterObj.objects[i].propertyOrMethod`.

Comment: This is really basic data structure use. If you don't know how to use arrays, you need to read a tutorial, I'm not going to try to teach you the basics.

Comment: I know about arrays. But I said that I would like to have MasterObj.obj1.propertyOrMethod, not MasterObj.objects[i].propertyOrMethod. This way I would need to know which index represents obj1, obj2, etc. Did you understand?

Comment: Why would you want that, it makes everything more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want it, but you can do it by putting all the objects in an array, then loop over the array and use dynamic property names.

```
let objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3, ...];
objects.forEach((i, obj) => MasterObj['obj' + (i+1)] = obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who answered my question. But, I solved the problem by creating modules for each object and importing via

```
import * as MasterObj from ...
```

This way, I got the structure I wanted:

```
MasterObject.obj1.propertiesAndMethods,
MasterObject.obj2.propertiesAndMethods, and so one...
```

Thanks!